# Spring data - mongoDB - get all Contacts containing agentNumberContainers

Tags: mongodb, find, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Contact class in my Spring - mongoDB application which looks like this:

```
public class Contact {

  ...
  private List<AgentNumberContainer> agentNumberContainers;   

}
```

The AgentNumberContainer- class looks like this:

```
public class AgentNumberContainer implements Comparable<AgentNumberContainer> {

private String contactTenant;
private String customerNumber;

@Override
public int compareTo(final AgentNumberContainer agentNumberContainer) {
    if (agentNumberContainer.getContactTenant().equals(this.contactTenant)
        && agentNumberContainer.getCustomerNumber().equals(this.customerNumber)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Now I will find all contacts in mongodb database which contains one or more of my agentNumberContainers. Therefore I have tried this:

```
public interface ContactRepository extends MongoRepository<Contact, String> {

    List<Contact> findByAgentNumberContainersIn(final List<AgentNumberContainer> agentNumberContainers);

}
```

but nothing is found. Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: try `findByAgentNumberContainersContaining`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AgentNumberContainer` class must implements `equals/hashCode` for equality check.